# Image server path ASP.NET Including controller and method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image

I am having a problem deleting an image in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application.
I am creating a user management module of an application which requires images/photos of the staff uploaded. However, since the profile should be editable, the image should be made possible to be deleted. But when I try to delete the image, I find it difficult locating the correct path of the image. When I use

`var fileToDelete = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~Content/photos/people/"),updatedStaff.Photo);
                            System.IO.File.Delete(fileToDelete);`
or

```
`var fileToDelete = Server.MapPath("~Content/photos/people/"+updatedStaff.Photo);
                        System.IO.File.Delete(fileToDelete);`
```

The path returned for the image is wrong in that, it contains the controller and method in the path and so I cannot delete the image.

This is the error message I get:

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Josh\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EduPlus\EduPlus\staffmembers\edit\~Content\photos\people\de1e1cf0-d.jpg'

"staffmembers" is the controller and "edit" is the method

Please I will appreciate any assistance to figure out the problem.

Thank you

Comment: "~Content"  is this correct? Maybe must be "~/Content"

Comment: Yes. That's it. Thank you very much. That's the omission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~/` is what you need to use before `Content`, not just `~` .

This should work perfectly fine.

```
var fileToDelete = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/photos/people"),
                                                                     updatedStaff.Photo);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's the omission